# Final Setup of gcc in Notepad++ [using nppexec]

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, notepad++

I downloaded notepad++, and MinGW
also I installed the nppexec plugin in order to use npp as fully functional IDE.

the command i entered into the nppexec is

```
npp_save
cd $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
gcc -o $(NAME_PART) $(FILE_NAME)
$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe
```

now, every time I hit "f6", it lets me to set the command, every single time, how do i stop it? I want to do that if I press F6 the command automatically be executed

second question.

my code, 4 example is:

```
printf("please enter num\n\n");
int a,b,c;
scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
c=a+b;
printf(" %d+%d equals %d", a, b, c);
```

but the output is in wrong order, first it asks for the scanf character and them prints out the FIRST message

```
1 3
please enter num

 1+3 equals 4
```

Thank you for the help,
Samyon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use the commands `npp_save` and `npp_run`:

```
npp_save
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
cmd /c del "$(NAME_PART)".o "$(NAME_PART)".exe *.o
gcc -o $(NAME_PART) $(FILE_NAME)
npp_run "$(NAME_PART)".exe
```

NPP_RUN is the key here.

Comment: This thing listens to pipes, and when nothing is entered, just finishes. Flushing some content with `fflush(stdout);` before using `scanf()` might work...