# Are there any scripts for compiling C code with cygwin for nppexec?

Tags: c, cygwin, notepad++

I'm currently learning to code in C and I use Cygwin64 to compile the code, as of now I'm using Notepad++ as my text editor and I would like to be able to compile my code using the plugin nppexec instead of having to close notepad++, compile and then open it again. The only problem is that the majority of nppexec scripts for C use mingw and not cygwin, Are there any nppexec scripts for C that use cygwin64?

Comment: Install eclipse, stop wasting time.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a fully fledged IDE, preferably with nativ support for C++. there are some beyond excellent free options in 2020 like e.g. Visual Studio Community and a few more.

Comment: Notepad++ is just fine for a starter IDE. When you outgrow that, geany is the next step up. Full IDEs do a lot of work for you, but it much better to understand the basics of editing, compiling and linking before moving to a full IDE. Learning to use an IDE is not trivial, each one is different, and if you don't have one, your will be stuck, if you don't know the basics.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this: [Final Setup of gcc in Notepad++ [using nppexec]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730556/final-setup-of-gcc-in-notepad-using-nppexec) ?

Notepad++ is a great program, but it's hardly an IDE. It doesn't understand your code so it can't do smart code completion and doesn't allow you to do any debugging.

For example [Code::Blocks](http://codeblocks.org/) is a good free IDE.

Also, if you want to learn C, I don't see why you use Cygwin. Only use Cygwin if you really need to port Linux/Unix stuff to Windows that won't build with other toolchains.

You should go for MinGW-w64 instead.

Comment: I'm only using a text editor because the book I am learning C from (Learn C the Hard way by Zed Shaw) recommends it for learning new languages.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any scripts for compiling C code with cygwin for nppexec?

### Do yourself a favor, learn to use the [command line interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface).

Read the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book.

Avoid weird characters (notably spaces) in C source file names. So use `foo-bar.c` or `foo_bar.c` but not `foo bar.c` (with a space after second `o`).

For your [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-code_editor), consider [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [vim](https://vim.org/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (or some other [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) of your choice). But remember that most C [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) programs (including [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler), [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/), [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) -which `cygwin` provides-, [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), even [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/) is at heart its `cl` command) are transforming a C [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (practically your `foo.c` file) into an [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) (e.g. `foo.obj` on Windows, `foo.o` on Linux or MacOSX) and don't have natively any GUI for that. Later some [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) is needed.

Compile thru a [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool such as [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

Use a [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), such as [git](https://git-scm.com/).

In many cases, it is interesting to *generate* some of your C code (so called [meta-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) approaches). Look into tools like [SWIG](http://swig.org/), [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/), [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [rpcgen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN), or those supporting [ASN-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) listed [here](http://ivmaiasn.sourceforge.net/asn1lnk.html). For GUI interfaces, consider using [GTK](https://gtk.org/) and related [code generator](https://sourceforge.net/directory/development/codegen/) tools, such as [Ggen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ggen/). For [JSONRPC](https://www.jsonrpc.org/) services, see [jsvggen](https://github.com/solidfire/jsvcgen). With a command line interface approach, taking advantage of these tools is easy. Look also, for inspiration, into the open source code of many [bootstrapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)) [source to source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) compilers [emitting C code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065), such as [Bigloo](https://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/) or [Chicken/Scheme](https://www.call-cc.org/) or [S48](http://s48.org/).

Learn to [use a debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), such as [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) or [LLDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLDB_(debugger)). Debugging information (e.g. [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF)) needs special flags at compilation time, so with GCC, use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get warnings and debug info.
[Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) is wrapping the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler.

For embedded cross-compilation for [Arduino](https://arduino.cc) or [RaspBerryPI](https://raspberrypi.org/) devices, the C [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) is also a command-line tool.

#### Spend several days to read the documentation of [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/docs.html) and [of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/).

Of course, read the documentation of every tool mentioned here.

Cygwin is [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) inspired, so be aware of the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy).

[NppExec](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec) is a plugin for [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) which has its documentation somewhere.

For inspiration, study the source  code of existing open source software on [github](https://github.com/) and [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/).

PS. Consider perhaps installing a newbie-friendly [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) such as [Debian](https://debian.org/) or [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.org/) on your PC laptop (if you prefer the original: a good GNU/Linux distribution to its imitation: Cygwin). Be sure to backup your important data before trying. You'll need a hundred gigabytes of disk space to be at ease, and you could have a dual boot setting: Linux for software development, Windows for games.

PPS: every software mentioned above (except some MicroSoft compilers) is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) and exists on Debian or on Ubuntu. You could *later* be interested by [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/). Read also for your information [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report (work in progress in June 2020).

Comment: yes, CLI is great and gives you the opportuninty to do many things much faster than usual GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin includes the mingw cross-compilers. Look for the mingw64-i686-gcc-g++ and mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++ packages in cygwin setup. These are almost the same compiler packages you can install with pacman when you have installed the mingw64 system.

In your makefile, change CC=gcc to CC=/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe to compile 64 bit exe's, or CC=/bin/x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe for 32 bit exe's. The resulting executables do not depend on the cygwin DLL. In the simplest cases, they only depend on windows DLLs.

There is a huge collection of mingw64 packages available to install.

Answer (score -2):

### Do yourself a favour, do not learn to use the command line at this stage.

If you use Windows 10 install VisualStudio

You do need cygwin anymore as Windows 10 has native Linux subsystem. You can install your favourite distribution there (I would recommend the Ubuntu as the instructions are for Ubuntu).

Follow the instruction: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/

Enjoy.

When you learn C a bit you can start to learn make or other build systems. Learning command line GDB IMO in 21st century is not needed at all. There are so many convenient GUIs and integrated environments for it

Comment: I don't really agree. If you plan to develop for more operating systems than just Windows it's good to know some command line, as this is what they have in common. I (virtually) went to Microsoft's Open Source summit yesterday and even there it was mentioned by Microsoft people that they believe command line is there to stay. That's why they focus so much on PowerShell and why they have brought the bash shell to Windows.

The Linux subsystem is great for developers and techies, but that won't be the target for Windows software that is distributed. That's why MinGW-w64 is so succesful.

Comment: @BrechtSanders the OP learns C. He is far from the problems you wrote about. To learn C, to expremint, change something IDE with graphics debugger is 100% the best.

Comment: The [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book *explicitly* recommend using the command line.

Comment: The Linux subsystem on Windows is called [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).